# Identity of Initial Elements in a Category

Tags: category-theory

I don't know much (really, anything) about Category Theory or Structural Set Theory, but I happened across [this blog post](http://m-phi.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/uniqueness-in-structural-set-theories-ii.html#comment-form) which piqued my interest. The author claims:

> But in Structural Set Theories, like ETCS and SEAR, one cannot prove uniqueness of mathematical objects, and, in particular, the uniqueness of the empty set. Instead, an empty set is defined as an initial object in a certain category. (Lawvere (1964) gave the first categorical characterization of the set-theoretic universe.) And while one can prove that initial objects are (uniquely) isomorphic, one cannot prove that initial objects are identical: one cannot express that they are identical.
>
> So---at least as I now understand it---in category theory, one can't
> prove, for objects $X,Y$ in a category $C$, a uniqueness claim: $$\big(\operatorname{Initial}_C(X)\land\operatorname{Initial}_C(Y)\big)\to X=Y$$ And this is merely because one can't express identity of objects: $$X=Y\;.$$

Is this accurate? Does Category Theory (and Structural Set Theory) typically make do without an identity predicate between objects? Are there serious obstacles to introducing one? If so, what are they?

Comment: Category doesn't handle identity very well, and isn't built to handle identity. It instead trafficks in isomorphism, which is identity you can detect using functions.

Comment: @Kris Why doesn't it handle identity very well?

Comment: You might like the [discussion of the “principle of equivalence” at the nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/principle+of+equivalence).

Comment: @RobinHouston VERY helpful, especially the second paragraph of the Logic and Foundations section: "All the same, a structural set theory built on first-order logic with equality automatically gives this question (whether two arbitrary sets are equal) a meaning, as do the most common forms of foundational type theory, but this is again never used in mathematics. (SEAR, which is based on first-order logic without equality, does not give this question a meaning and does not suffer for it.) So just as we don't need to ask whether (0,0)=2, we don't need to ask whether {(0,0)}={2} as sets."

Comment: the comment by @Kris , taken at face value, is meaningless. Established mathematical theories (like Category theory) are always logically consistent. otherwise they are discarded right away (just like Frege's naive set theory). Category theory is based on logic with equality and equality is used extensively for ex. to test whether a morphism is monic or epic. The point of category theory, as explained also by Qiaochu Yuan, is that the properties that we should care about should be invariant for isomorphic objects....

Comment: ...Isomorphism is a derived concept in category theory and its definition depends on equality (the composition of a morphism with its inverse is EQUAL to the identity morphism)

Answer (score 8):

No, this is false. A category first of all has a [class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)) of objects, and relative to a fixed formalization of a notion of set theory with classes, equality of two elements of a class is a perfectly well-defined notion.

The insight of category theory is that even if one *can* talk about equality, in many situations it is better *not to*, and talking about isomorphism is better.

Comment: An analogy is the observation is that you cannot distinguish between different roots of a polynomial from a field which does not contain those roots. For example, $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(-i)$ are isomorphic and behave identically with regards to any application. So although $i$ and $-i$ are definitely nonequal, it is a matter of convention which one we consider to be the "real" root of -1.

Comment: What about identity across categories? Is that well-defined, or only identity of elements within the domain of a single category?

Comment: Also, is the claim that can't prove X=Y from the claim that both X and Y are initial objects from the same category false, or just the claim that category theory can't express identity?

Comment: @Dennis: that depends on your axiomatization of set theory. My personal preference is that it is meaningless to ask whether two elements of different sets are identical (this question is not well-typed), but this is a preference I have about set theory, not category theory. For your second question, that claim is true because it's just not true that initial objects are identical in general. (But from a category-theoretic perspective, what counts is that any two initial objects are isomorphic by a unique isomorphism. This is in practice as good as identity.)

Comment: @Dennis: I agree with Yuan here. That its perfectly possible to ask whether x=y, but from the philosophical point-of-view of category theory its often not important, and (hence possibly the formalisation of category theory should not include the concept of equality - except I've noticed sometimes some concepts do require it, but which they qualify as 'evil', perhaps indicating that the concept there needs further clarifying).

Comment: @Dennis: It is generally true what is important, as Yuan points out, is that two initial objects are isomorphic by a unique isomorphism, BUT suppose the isomorphism is not unique, say that there are two, one could then ask for a 'higher' level isomorphism between them - and this is where higher category theory comes in. But, probably whats important is to see why its useful to say initial objects are isomorphic, and thats probably best demonstrated in the context of some universal construction. (though I prefer the name characterising construction because that better describes what it does).

Answer (score 2):

Well, in category theory based on the "ordinary" set theory there are no obstacles of using identity predicate. But in category theory you normally use objects that are determined up to isomorphism and it's all that matters.

You have objects and morphisms. If there is an isomorphism between two objects then they are identical from your point of view: you can't distinguish them in terms of any of their properties that can be examined in your world: world of objects and morphisms.

I'll not comment on the structural set theory part of the question, since I don't have much knowledge about it. But I like the idea of different empty sets - for IT specialists it is for example very natural to distiguish between empty set of integers and empty set of reals (floats). And it was quite shocking for me when I first saw in my set theory course that it is possible that $\alpha \in \beta$ and $\alpha \subseteq \beta$ at the same time. Afaik, with type theory and  different empty sets you introduce some hierarchy and avoid such pathologies.